# How to remove last menu border style

Tags: html, css

Sorry, May be this is a simple question, How can remove border for menu 4, because I dont want border for last menu

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 4</a></li>       
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Css

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a::before {
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
bottom: 0;
content: "";
height: 1px;
left: 20px;
position: absolute;
width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried Some code its working..

```
.dropdown li:last-child a::before {
border : none ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with pseudo CSS selectors.

```
.dropdown li:last-child a{
    border : none;
    /*more styles here*/
}
```

Comment: Try adding important or something

Comment: Tried with important but not working. I think we need some other code for ::before selector

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are you trying to add a border using pseudo-elements with an :after selector.

Here is a fiddle of what You might be after:

**[>Fiddle<](https://jsfiddle.net/1vz39z4m/)**

And Your markup was incorrect, you had a hanging `</li>` element there.

Comment: I tried selecter because I only need border half, not full width. On your fiddle border bottom shows full width of menu

Comment: In this case you shouldn't be using border-bottom, you can just set a one pixel height and 50% width for the pseudo element.